# How can I use emailjs-mime-parser?

Tags: javascript, email, mime, multipart

I got emails from imapserver using [emailjs-imap-client](https://github.com/emailjs/emailjs-imap-client).

```
imapCient.listMessages('INBOX', '1:25', ['uid', 'flags', 'body.peek[]']).then(messages => {})
```

and I tried to body  using [emailjs-mime-parser](https://github.com/emailjs/emailjs-mime-parser)

```
import parser from 'emailjs-mime-parser';

const myMimeNodes = parser(messages[0]['body[]']);
```

It is no problem myMimeNodes does not have children(I mean it's not multipart).

new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(myMimeNodes.content)

But messages is multipart, myMimeNodes has children(mimeNodes).

How can I get readable html file with images?

Comment: are you looking for a way that always gets you the HTML message, if it's multipart or if it isn't

Comment: thank you for your comment. Yes I am looking for how can I get readable HTML file generate from multipart message.

Comment: I'd just check `typeof myMimeNodes == Object` and then if true, get the child nodes. You can check the child nodes' keys by `console.log`'ing myMimeNodes

Comment: What happens when yo console.log it?

Comment: console.log(myMineNodes);
`
[Object]
 0: mime:MimeNode
    bodystructre:
   charset:
   childNodes: Array(number)
         0: MimeNodes
  contentTransferEncoding:
  contentType:
 header: Array(number)
 headers: object

`
childNodes have content: Uint8Array



Please tell me how can I restructure body from childNodes.content.